# Getting from series solutions of Airy's equation to the Airy functions Ai(x) and Bi(x)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, airy-functions

If I solve the Airy differential equation ($ {y'' - xy = 0}$) using the power series method, I get the following solution:

$y(x) = a_0 \left(1 + \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^6}{180} + \cdots \right) + a_1 \left(x + \frac{x^4}{12} + \frac{x^7}{504} + \cdots \right)$

However, everywhere I research the Airy differential equation, I see answers in terms of $Ai(x)$ and $Bi(x)$, which are expressed using gamma functions and fractional powers of 3.

My question is how do we get from the series solution (where I am at) to $Ai(x)$ and $Bi(x)$?

Comment: Look at [DLMF equations 9.4.1 and 9.4.3](https://dlmf.nist.gov/9.4).

Comment: Being lazy, I typed in $OEIS$ : $1,6,180$ and $1,12,504$

Comment: @Somos Thanks a bunch! That really helped me understand the Airy function.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you very much too! That's a very useful website and helped answer my question :)

Comment: @Somos https://oeis.org/A176730: This website has you referenced several times! I was wondering if you would mind telling me what a(n) and b(n) are (mathematically, as a formula), because I'm having trouble understanding the code?